# Ajax Call From PHP File TO a PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is a ajax call i did in my php file :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../includes/filters.php",
                data: {"email" : email},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    if(data.equals('sent'))
                     {  
                        alert(data);
                     }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("There Was Some Problem Please Try Again!");
                    }

                },
                    error: function(xhr, status, text) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(text);
                    }
              });
```

and here is the filters.php file :

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $query = "---------some query------";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);                 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $temp = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($temp == 1)         
        return json_encode('true');
        else 
        return json_encode('false');
```

here is the error i am getting in the consol

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
(index):120 parsererror
(index):121 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/pedagoge/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:5497)
    at ub (http://localhost/pedagoge/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:7521)
    at x (http://localhost/pedagoge/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:10935)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b (http://localhost/pedagoge/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:14765)
```

please help me out, since i have already tried all the JSON conversion, i even tried converting a php variable with a string in it, no lead

Comment: What is `data.equals()`? Are you confusing Javascript with Java?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` the JSON response, not `return` it.

```
echo json_encode($temp == 1 ? 'true' : 'false');
```

Also, your Javascript code expects the response to be `sent` when it's successful, not `true` or `false`.

And in Javascript, you compare things with `==`, not `.equals()`:

```
if (data == "sent")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no output from `filters.php`; you need to `echo` instead of `return`.

Without using JSON:

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $query = "---------some query------";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);  // XXX $mysqli is not initialized
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);                 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    echo $stmt->num_rows == 1 ? "sent" : "not-sent";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the result of your `json_encode('true');` does not actually constitute valid JSON, which you have specified in your ajax call as the `dataType` you are expecting the result to be returned as, which is why you are getting the parse error.

```
echo json_encode('true');
```

Gives

```
"true"
```

Not a json string by any stretch of the imagination.

Try this instead

```
$result = array();
$result['status'] = 'not sent';

if ($temp == 1) {
    $result['status'] = 'sent';
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Now in your javascript success function

```
success: function(data) 
{
    if(data.status == 'sent') {  
        alert(data.status);
    } else {
        alert("There Was Some Problem Please Try Again!");
    }

},
```